# Read file and use for-loop to get a product of each line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop

I am creating a script that will read a text-file, which contains numbers, let's call it "numbers.txt":

```
1234
20324
221
etc.
```

I want to multiply the first number in the text-file with the second and subtract 1, the second with the third, etc., until the the whole number is multiplied and subtracted by 1 in each step. The problem is that when it runs, it will output all the values it gets, while I only want the end product of each line and put it in a variable. How do I do it?

Here is my code:

```
fid = fopen('numbers.txt');
     while ~feof(fid);
     fgetlfid = fgetl(fid);
     c = 1;
         for i = fgetlfid;
          c = i*c-1   
          end
     end
```

Comment: You should put a semicolon after `c = i*c-1` to suppress output. Then put a `disp(c)` at the end to display the final value

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have done this, but this also displays the output of each mathematical operation, while I only need the last one of each line (where all the numbers on that line is multiplied and subtracted by 1)

Comment: Several questions: 1) Are all numbers in the file positive integers? 2) Does the entire file fit in the memory at once? If so, you might be able to load it all using i.e. `dlmread`, `textscan` etc. (`A = dlmread('numbers.txt');` or `fID = fopen('numbers.txt'); B = textscan(fID,'%u'); B = B{1}; fclose(fID);`)

Comment: It is only positive integers, and they all fit in memory.

Comment: @anters - The implementation above is slightly different than your description. Should the first step be the first number multiplied by 1 and subtract 1 (as in your code) or the first number multiplied by the second number and subtract 1 (as in your description)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects to your question:

- **Reading a text file** - See Dev-iL's suggestion in the comments to read the full file into memory rather than using `fgetl`.
- **Parsing a string of numbers into a vector of numbers** - After you've read in the text file, you need to convert a string (e.g. '1234') into a vector (e.g. [1 2 3 4]).
- **Computing the sum described in your question** - This seems to be the crux of your question so I'll focus on this below.

For a string of characters `abcd` where a, b, c and d are integers between 0 and 9, the sum you describe is computed as:

```
( ( (a - 1) * b - 1 ) * c - 1 ) * d - 1
```

This can be expanded to:

```
a*b*c*d - b*c*d - c*d - d - 1
```

The pattern is clear. For any vector `x` of integers between 0 and 9, the sum can be calculated in a vectorized way by:

```
temp = flip( cumprod( flip( x ) ) );
result = temp(1) - sum( temp(2:end) ) - 1
```

For example:

```
>> x = [ 1 2 3 4 ];
>> temp = flip( cumprod( flip( x ) ) )

temp =

    24    24    12     4

>> result = temp(1) - sum( temp(2:end) ) - 1

result =

   -17
```

Applying this in a vectorized way to the whole file is a bit tricky as you can have strings of different lengths. You can do this through some creative uses of padding your strings with NaN so that each row is the same length. Again, I only focused on the meat of your question and left the rest up to you.